# kernel module: extern only if a specific parameter is set

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I would like to use a function defined in another kernel module.
Usually you do this like this:

**the other module**

```
void do_sth() {
  /* ... */
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(do_sth);
```

**my_module**

```
extern void do_sth();

void some_function(void) {
  /* ... */
  do_sth();
  /* ... */

}
```

In my case, I only want to use the function `do_sth()` if the `other_module` is installed or, alternatively, if a specific parameter is set for my module (sth. like `use_other_module=y`)

The problem is, that - as soon as I declare the functions as `extern` (globally) - the module cannot be loaded anymore when the `other_module` is not installed or loaded.

**So my questions are:**

- Is there a way to determine if a symbol is exported at runtime?
- Is there a way to define a symbol globally as extern from within a function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to export symbol from kernel module in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769368/how-to-export-symbol-from-kernel-module-in-this-case)

Comment: The *other_module* should register itself in the *my_module* and provide a set of callbacks. Similar case is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769368/how-to-export-symbol-from-kernel-module-in-this-case/

Comment: But what If I am not able to change the other Module? Thank you anyway, the Idea is awesome

Comment: If you know the symbol name you may try to look for it in the linker symbol table.

Comment: If you dont have to make the decision on run timer if the other module should be present or not you may wrap up the `extern ...` under `ifdefs`.

Comment: You might be able to do something using `symbol_get` defined in `<linux/module.h>`. For example, if you have a function pointer `static void (*my_do_sth)(void);`, you can assign it at run-time using `my_do_sth = symbol_get(do_sth);`. If that fails, `my_do_sth` will be `NULL`, otherwise it will point to the function. It should be paired with a call to `symbol_put_addr(my_do_sth);` or `symbol_put(do_sth);` to release the reference.

Comment: @IanAbbott That's the solution I think! I will give it a try and report.

Comment: @IanAbbott That's it! Thank you so much! If you reformulate it as an official answer I will mark this issue as solved and your answer as the accepted one

Comment: I've never used it before myself. It was just a suggestion for something for you to investigate. I suggest you submit your own answer with your findings.

Comment: I will do so as soon as I tried all cases ;) Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment of Ian Abbott, here is one possible solution:

In **my_module**:

1. declare the function as extern, otherwise the compiler will complain about the do_sth in symbol_get()

   ```
   extern void do_sth();
   ```
2. declare a pointer which later will point to the function do_sth in the other module

   ```
   void (*__do_sth)();
   ```
3. assign the pointer, increment the use counter so that the kernel knows that somebody is using the other module

   ```
   __do_sth = symbol_get(do_sth);
   if (__do_sth)
       __do_sth();
   ```
4. On module removal, or maybe earlier when you don't need the other module anymore: Decrement the use counter. Otherwise it will be impossible to remove the other module since the kernel thinks it is still in use

   ```
   if (__do_sth)
       symbol_put(do_sth);
   ```
5. Furthermore, you will have to make sure that the other module is somehow loaded as needed, I use a UDEV rule for that.

Comment: Shouldn't the code call `__do_sth()` rather than `do_sth()`? Otherwise, **my_module** is still linked directly to `do_sth` in **other_module**, making this trick a bit pointless.