# How to export variables in between two modules?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have two modules mod_X.ko and mod_Y.ko. I have defined a variable var in mod_X/ as follows:

File filex.c

```
int var = 1000;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(var);
```

File filex.h

```
extern int var;
```

In mod_Y/:
File filey.c

```
#include "filex.h"
extern int var;
```

The Makefile in Y properly includes the filex.h header file / directory.

Still, I am unable to load module Y as it is giving the following error while performing an insmod:

```
mod_Y: Unknown symbol var (err 0)
```

FYI, mod_X is already loaded prior to loading mod_Y.

Please help.

Comment: Most likely, the message `mod_Y: Unknown symbol var (err 0)` when you trying to *load* module Y is not the first sign of the problem: you should get "undefined reference" warning when **build** the module Y. Do you have such warning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export symbol from Linux kernel module in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769368/how-to-export-symbol-from-linux-kernel-module-in-this-case)